# Error TS2345: Argument of type 'Product | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Product[] | PromiseLike<Product[]>'

Tags: angular, typescript

Got a problem when try to get my products by ID

[Te code its here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xLKok.png)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your types aren't matching.

the const productfound will either be of the type product or undefined
the returntype you have defined is a product[]

Those two don't match

The most obvious thing would be to change the returntype to product, since it is a getById anyway. (You only expect one and just one item to be returned, so why an array?)

I'm not used to work with promises, so let my know if you figured it out.

Take care and good luck.